# Adding Event Listeners to dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Working on a fun side project and ran into a little trouble.
Basically, I have a page that allows a user to login to Spotify. I then redirect them to a page that puts their top 10 artists into a card with the artists name, picture, and a little button to view upcoming shows. I would like to link that button to a function I already wrote in another script that will pull their specified artists upcoming concerts.

The trouble I'm running into is accessing the buttons I'm creating.
Here's the full function I'm running:

```
async function fetchArtists() {
  return await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists', settings)
  .then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((data) => {
      let listOfArtists = data.items.slice(0, 10).map((item) => {
        return {
         name: item.name, 
         picture: item.images[1].url
        }
      })
      //console.log(listOfArtists)
      return listOfArtists;


    }).then((listOfArtists) => {
      listOfArtists.forEach((artist) => {
        let createCard = document.createElement('div');
        createCard.class = "card"
        createCard.style = "width: 40% height: 40%"
        createCard.innerHTML = `
        <div class="row card-row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card bg-transparent text-black text-center ">
              <img src="${artist.picture}" class="card-img rounded-circle shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-black rounded" alt="...">
                <div class="card-img-overlay"></div>
                  <div class="card-footer font-weight-bold bg-transparent">${artist.name}
                  <div class="row-md-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark">View Upcoming Shows</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


        let container = document.querySelector(".artist-grid")
        container.appendChild(createCard)
      })
});
}
```

This is working almost exactly how I want it, and outputs this:
The problem is I can't seem to get an event listener to work on the buttons.
I tried adding this code inside of my forEach, below the last

```
myButton = document.querySelector(".btn")
myButton.addEventListener("click, () => {
console.log("Test to see if button onclick works")
```

And it doesn't output anything to the console on click. So I ran a console log of myButton and it showed 10 buttons, so not sure what the disconnect is if it looks seems like I am able to access them.

Comment: [Output link]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOWWf.png)

Comment: **Where** is the `addEventListener` code? Is it inside the `.then()`, after the `forEach()`?

Comment: Hey Tyler! It is right after the last </div> and above the let container = document.querySelector(".artist-grid"). So it is inside the forEach() loop

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it is because you forgot the double quote after click?
myButton.addEventListener("click, () => {
     console.log("Test to see if button onclick works")
should be replaced with
myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
     console.log("Test to see if button onclick works")

Comment: Hey laserany. If this were the case, then the question should be closed as a typo instead of answered, as it won't help anyone else in the future.

Comment: I think you may be right. This is my first day contributing so I'm still not aware of all the clickable options in stackoverflow

Comment: No worries. You won't have enough reputation to comment on questions I don't think, so in the meantime just look for questions that you can provide a complete answer to. Your answer here may not be wrong, it's just better suited as a comment instead :) Happy coding, and welcome!

Comment: Thanks body. I sure will next time :)

Comment: Hey Laser, thanks for the reply! That unfortunately didn't fix anything but thanks for trying, it's driving me crazy---ah!

Comment: how about adding an id to your buttons and then creating your MyButton using that id? sometimes querying using classes doesn't end up well specially when you have so many div elements indented

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things it could be:

- Does the button require a `z-index` bring it to the front?
- Does the button or any parent element have `pointer-events: none;`?
- Are you calling `addEventListener` after the append?
- Has the DOM operation finished by the time you try to add the event listeners?
- You're using querySelector here but do you want to add a click listener to all buttons, or just one?

If your problem is JS related you could try iterating over those buttons and wrapping the addEventListener operation in a timeout, so the DOM append has buffer to finish, and you can debug further, something like:

```
async function fetchArtists() {
// ...

}).then((listOfArtists) => {
  // ...

  container.appendChild(createCard);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`.btn`);

    buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
      console.log(`Button ${index} [query]: `, button);

      button.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
        console.log(`Button ${index} [click]: `, e);
      });
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey court, thanks so much I will try your solutions. Basically, I want to add a click listener to all buttons. I've tried calling the addEventListener before and after the append, and neither works. It doesn't require a Z index, no point-events: none, and to the best of my knowledge the DOM operation has created my buttons before I try to add an event listener to them. I will try your solution and report back!